# what is an abstract activity?

Tags: meaning

Could somebody explain to me what an abstract activity is? I have looked in several dictionaries but it is not clear. I mean in a general sense, nothing to do with computer science! Is it something like a separate activity, not connected to another?

Comment: Can you give any context? I have never heard the phrase before.

Comment: There no special meaning in general.  It is an activity that is abstract.  Perhaps in a particular context this question could be answered fully, but as it stands it is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

*Abstract* is from a Latin word meaning "pulled away, detached," and the basic idea is of **something detached from physical, or concrete, reality**. It is frequently used of ideas, meaning that they don't have a clear applicability to real life, and of art, meaning that it doesn't pictorially represent reality. It is also used as a *noun*, especially in the phrase "in the abstract" , and as a *verb* (accented on the second syllable), meaning "to remove."

So if I understand well:

> Counting from 1 to 10 in your head

is an exemple of abstract activity.

[Source](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abstract)